# Flutter: Enable button when RatingBar value has been set

Tags: button, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and am trying to figure out how to enable my action button only when a rating value has been selected in an AlertDialog. When the "submit" button has been selected with nothing selected, it still changes the value to e.g. 6.0 for some odd reason so an "if" statement may not work comparing it to null as I've tried it previously in the onPressed() method.

This is my method code to show the AlertDialog:

```
void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Pain Rating"),
        content: RatingBar(
        onRatingChanged: (rating) { 
          setState(() { 
            _rating = rating;
            print("rating changed: rating = $_rating");
          });
        },
    maxRating: 10,
    filledIcon: Icons.radio_button_checked,
    emptyIcon: Icons.radio_button_unchecked,
    isHalfAllowed: false,
    filledColor: Colors.green,
    emptyColor: Colors.green,
    size: 28,
  ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: const Text('SUBMIT'),
        onPressed: () {
          print("submit pressed: rating = $_rating");
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
      )
    ],
    );
  });
```

Currently when any or no rating has been selected and the "submit" button has been pressed it will close the dialog. I expect the "submit" button to be disabled until a rating has been selected

Answer (score 0):

This is one suggested way to do it:

```
var _rating = 0.0

FlatButton(
    child: const Text('SUBMIT'),
    onPressed: _rating > 0.0 
        ? () {
          print("submit pressed: rating = $_rating");
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        } : null,
)
```

If your `_rating` gets grater than 0, that means the used changed the value (assuming your rating can't be 0). If so, you enable the button by passing that `VoidCallback`... if not, the `null` value is called and that disables the button.

If by any reason you need the 0.0 value, then use a `bool` variable and change the value to true once you reach the `onRatingChanged` callback and then change my logic from `_rating > 0.0` to simply your bool variable.

Comment: Hi Mariano, I've tried this in my code, adding prints to the console and it definitely goes inside the "true" part of the if statement however it isn't enabling the button. Only when I refresh the emulator does it allow enable it

Comment: If your boolean changed inside your setState? Because, if not, the build method will not be notified of changes.

Comment: Yes, my boolean becomes set to true inside setState